# How to include multiple .py files in Python project in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, file

I'm trying to write a python project. I would like to describe 2 classes in each their .py file, creating a sqlite3 database in a separate .py file and loading test data into the database in it's own .py file.

Then I want to build and run the project from some .py file, e.g. main.py.

How do I make sure all the .py files are run and being accessible from my main.py file? Is there a setting in Python or Visual Studio that lets you define which files the project are made up of?

My file structure:

[image: my file structure]

Answer (score 0):

this que is not that much relevent... the concept of using multiple .py files or any in other languages their is the option which as "import xyz.py".
also there is issue while python in visual studio.
aftre reading documentation knew that at time of compiling we can link the files which are depencding oR can effect in main.py file.

```
<Compile Include="\test2.py">
    <Link>MyProject\test2.py</Link>
</Compile>
```

before comping/execution.